# Mostrar tres imágenes centradas con Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Tengo tres imágenes con su overlay pero me salen de lado izquierdo. Lo que necesito es que queden centradas las tres imágenes con ayuda de Bootstrap usando el *col.md*, *col.sm*.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="team-member col-md-3">
    <div class="member-thumb">
      <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="team-overlay">
        <h3>Ing. </h3>
        <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="team-member col-md-3">
          <div class="member-thumb">
            <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="team-overlay">
              <h3>Ing. </h3>
              <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
              <ul class="social">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="team-member col-md-3">
                <div class="member-thumb">
                  <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
                  <div class="team-overlay">
                    <h3>Ing. </h3>
                    <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
                    <ul class="social">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
```

Estoy haciendo como el equipo de trabajo que conforma el team.

Comment: Especifica en las etiquetas qué versión de bootstrap estás utilizando. Además, si vas a mostrar a través de un snippet tu código, no olvides agregar bootstrap como librería externa.

Comment: Bueno es bootstrap la ultima version , solo quiero que me ayudes a centrar usando el col

Comment: _team-member_, _member-thumb_, _team-overlay_ no son clases propias de Bootstrap. Recuerda mostrar un [repro] de lo que estás teniendo actualmente.

Comment: Puedes ver un ejemplo en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#variable-width-content)

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas o comentarios solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas:

- Cerrar apropiadamente los `div`
- Eliminar los `<div class="row">` intermedios si quieres que todo esté dentro de una misma fila
- Usar la clase `text-center`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="team-member col-md-3">
    <div class="member-thumb">
      <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="team-overlay">
        <h3>Ing. </h3>
        <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member col-md-3">
    <div class="member-thumb">
      <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="team-overlay">
        <h3>Ing. </h3>
        <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member col-md-3">
    <div class="member-thumb">
      <img src="images/r3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="team-overlay">
        <h3>Ing. </h3>
        <span>Ingeniero en Sistemas</span>
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejecuta el snippet en pantalla completa, y si no es lo que buscas, deja un comentario.